# Cycling through two strings character by character to find partial anagrams

Tags: objective-c, algorithm, for-loop, nsstring

Okay, so I'm trying to compare two strings, one eight letters long, one that could be anything from 3-8 letters long, to see if the shorter one could be made from letters in the longer one. Following some algorithms and tips I've got something which nearly works, but not in all cases.

The `haystack` and `needle` are fed in re-sorted into alphabetical order (for example, `tomatoes` would become `aemoostt` and `toe` would become `eot`). In some cases this works, but the issues arise if multiples of a letter exist. One such broken example is that it thinks `aaabrs` does exist inside `aabeirsz`, where obviously it should not since it has three A's in it.

If anyone can take a browse through my methods and spot where the issue is occurring, I'd be hugely, hugely grateful. Thanks in advance.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    BOOL doesWordExist = NO;
    doesWordExist = [self doesEightLetterWord: @"aabeirsz" containWord: @"aaabrs"];
    NSLog(doesWordExist ? @"Does it exist? Yes" : @"Does it exist? No");
}

- (BOOL) doesEightLetterWord: (NSString* )haystack containWord: (NSString *)needle {
    for (int i = 0; i < [needle length]; i++) {

        NSString *currentCharacter = [needle substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(i, 1)];
        NSCharacterSet *set = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString: currentCharacter];
        NSLog(@"Current character is %@", currentCharacter);
        if ([haystack rangeOfCharacterFromSet:set].location == NSNotFound) {
            NSLog(@"The letter %@ isn't found in the word %@", currentCharacter, haystack);
            return NO;
        } else {
            NSLog(@"The letter %@ is found in the word %@", currentCharacter, haystack);
            int currentLocation = [haystack rangeOfCharacterFromSet: set].location;
            currentLocation++;
            NSString *newHaystack = [haystack substringFromIndex: currentLocation];
            NSString *newNeedle = [needle substringFromIndex: i + 1];
            NSLog(@"newHaystack is %@", newHaystack);
            NSLog(@"newNeedle is %@", newNeedle);

            if ([newNeedle isEqualToString:@""]) {
                return YES;
            }
        }
    }

return NO;
}
```

Comment: "aaabrs does exist inside aabeirsz, where obviously it should not since it has three A's in it." That's not true, if I understand what you're trying to do. The shorter one can't be made from the longer one, since the longer one doesn't have enough a's.

Comment: aaabrs would require a word with three A's. aabeirsz has two A's. Ergo, it should not return YES, but it does. See the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the search for the character from `needle` always searches the entire `haystack`.  `newHaystack` is created correctly as the new substring from `haystack`, but it is never actually used. So, for example, the search for each character `a` always searches the entire original value `aabeirsz`.

Comment: That looks to be true, but how can I use `newHaystack` in an if statement if it's only created or set in the result of that if statement?

Comment: I suspect you would need to update haystack with the new haystack.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest that you further transform your input. After sorting by letter, build a frequency table that turns each string into a (letter, frequency) map. Then go through the shorter string's map and, for each key, if the key does not exist in the larger string's map or if the frequency in the larger string's map is smaller, reject as an anagram. Otherwise, it passes.

**EDIT** With the caveat that I am by no means an Objective C programmer, here's a stab at how to build a frequency table as an `NSCountedSet` for `haystack`:

```
NSCountedSet *haystackSet = [[NSCountedSet alloc] init];
NSUInteger len = [haystack length];
for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    unichar c = [haystack characterAtIndex:i];
    if ([[NSCharacterSet letterCharacterSet] characterIsMember:c])
        [haystackSet addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:c]];
}
```

Do the same for `needle` and then its a matter of iterating through the counts for `needle` and checking against the counts for `haystack`.

Comment: This one's a little over my head.. I don't quite know what a letter/frequency map would be. Would it be an NSDictionary for each word, with (for example, for aaabrs" be A = 3, B = 1, R = 1, S = 1)? Then I compare each key to one of the same name in the longer word (so comparing A's in aaabrs with A's in aabeirsz)? If so, how would I go about building such a dictionary from an NSString?

Comment: break your string into dictionary of letter(key) counts(value).

Comment: @lukech - I added some sample code. You can actually skip the sorting step, since it's not relevant to this approach.

Comment: Use Ruby.  Far easier.